# Appium v.1.4.13 Error :stdout maxBuffer exceeded

Tags: appium

I get "unzip threw error :stdout maxBuffer exceeded", I am using Appium .v1.4.13 .
maxBuffer is 524288. Tried to increase it by 50% & 100%. How can I fix it?

Comment: I was able to solve it by increasing the maxBuffer in the /lib/helpers.js file: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/88e67ce987d78ce44de252219e07dc176a3511c2/lib/helpers.js#L98 following: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5765